# Are KEY_TYPED events consumed by jxbrowser?

Tags: jxbrowser

I've added a key listener to a jxbrowser 6.11 BrowserView object to log keys typed by the user.  With this listener, I can see keyPressed and keyReleased events, but no keyTyped events.  Could jxbrowser be consuming the KEY_TYPED events for some reason?  And, if so, is there anything I can do about it?  Unfortunately, because of restrictions in the external method being used to process and log the key events, it has to be a KEY_TYPED event passed to it.

Comment: As it turns out, KEY_TYPED events are handled differently between heavyweight and lightweight browser types.  Switching to lightweight resolved the problem. (Thanks, Nikita!)

Answer (score 1):

KEY_TYPED event is processed properly in BrowserView for Browser instance that was created in LIGHTWEIGHT mode.